# Trouble in loading web view with http url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im just creating a webview app in react. in development time both http and https url links supported perfectly but after apk generation http links are not working how can i solve it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import WebView from 'react-native-webview'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'http://jobser.herokuapp.com/' }} style={{ marginTop: 20 }} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, But I fixed it by enabling `SSL` in my endpoints. `WebView` not rendering `Non-Secured Sites (Non SSL)` in production build, for security purposes.

**The GitHub Issue Still Not Solved** https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/990

I **strongly recommend** you to avoid `Non SSL Endpoints`, You can get **Free SSL** [Here](https://www.sslforfree.com/).

Comment: Correct answer. But since the app is on Heroku, I recommend OP to check how SSL is activated in there. IIRC, you need to activate $7 dyno and then apply free SSL cert from their addons.

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi Thank you for your comment, It seems very helpful to Heroku users.

Comment: Couldn't edit my comment anymore, but here's the link to the actual tutorial about Heroku and SSL activation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku

Comment: I really appreciate, If you update my answer with your comment!